# Stacked column in x and y-axis for second column only

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have following bar chart:

[image: Chartjs stacked bar charts in y]

I used following options to stack the chart on the x-axis:

```
public chartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{stacked: true}],
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

I would like to stack the second, right column (the two golden and grey bars on the right) also on the y-axis, so their values will sum up and will be shown as stacked value. The left column (blue and purple bars) should remain as it is and only use `xAxes: [{stacked: true}]`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Stacked on both axes...? I might be in the minority here but I'm not completely clear on what the final product would look like. Perhaps a quick image or example of what you're trying to achieve would help?

Comment: Here is an example: https://codepen.io/travishorn/pen/kkVKJG --> xAxes: [{ stacked: true }], yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]. I would like to do the same, but just for the bars on the right. – Tiero L. 1 hour ago